# Unix - jar file contents get cut off when I unzip

Tags: unix, jar

I am unzipping .war file in unix using the jar -tvf command and the contents are getting cutoff to the point where I can't scroll up and see the beginning.  I know this because I connected my laptop to an external monitor and was able to see a little more, but still not the beginning which is what I need.  Has anyone experienced this or know a potential solution?

Thank you.

Comment: So am I getting you right? The actual question has not much to do with jar, but with being able to get all the output in terminal?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: kk. Do you need it for later use or just that moment? You can pipe it into `more` and then go through the lines, by pressing `enter` or smthn, like this `jar -tvf <file> | more`.
I'd suggest, you change the question, so it better describes the problem and can be used by others as a source.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Syntac, that did the trick!